# Remove stuck steering gearbox mounting bolt?

Tags: power-steering, stuck-bolt

I'm removing the steering gearbox from my 2004 E-250.  I'm trying to remove the gearbox from the frame, but one of the three bolts that mount it to the frame is stuck.  I've managed to get the bolt out about halfway, but the more I unscrew it, the tighter it gets.  I can't get it out any further with the 15" breaker bar I've been using.

Other than turning really hard, the only thing I've done is spay it with a lot of WD-40.

Other info:  The two bolts that I did manage to get out had red-colored thread locking compound on them.

How do I get this bolt out of the gear box?

Comment: It sometimes helps to leave the WD-40 to "soak in" over night. I know it helps when removing a manifold.

Comment: Use a proper penetrating oil like liquid wrench or PB blaster for starters.

Answer (score 3):

I did some research on thread locking compound, and found that heat should be applied to the bolt to loosen its grip.  I heated the bolt using a standard small torch with MAP gas for about two minutes.  The bolt came out fine with about 80 ft-pounds of force.